# jQuery Form Plugin with 2 buttons

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I am using jQuery Form plugin
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="submit" id="submit1" type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Save" />
<input name="submit2" id="submit2" type="submit" class="submit_button" value="Send Sale" />
</form>
```

Ok, so there are two button one is to send a mail through ajax form and other one is to save the data into table. here is the Jquery i used.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// bind form using ajaxForm 
$('#submit2').click(function() {
    alert('ffff');
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: '.loading',
        beforeSubmit:  showImg,
        success: showResponse,
        url:       'send_sale.php',
    });
});
});
```

When i clicked on Save button its working fine but when i click on Send Sale first and just after that click on Save button, the Save Button doing the same process of Send Sale.

Does anyone know whats wrong ?

**UPDATE**
got the solution use ajaxSubmit instead of ajaxForm

Answer (score 0):

Just by being submit buttons inside the form tag, both buttons are submitting the form.  What you may want to try is moving converting the input submits to buttons and move them outside the form.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
<button id="submit1" class="submit_button">Save</button>
<button id="submit2" class="submit_button">Send Sale</button>
```

Then define your click handlers separately.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit1').click(function () {
    alert("action 1")
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({
        target: '.loading',
        beforeSubmit: showImg,
        success: showResponse,
        url: 'send_sale.php',
    });
    });
    $('#submit2').click(function () {
    alert("action 2")
    });
});
```